# Labeling horizontal bar using matplotlib bar_label

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart

I'd like to display the value of the bar on each bar with `pyplot.barh()` and `ax.bar_label`.

I've read the document https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/bar_label_demo.html but it didn't help. Please help.

```
# Prepare & sort the data
df = pd.DataFrame({"coins": ["BTC", "ETH", "BNB", "XRP", "SOL", "ADA"],
                   "dominance": [42.08, 19.38, 3.68, 1.73, 1.55, 1.51]})
df = df.sort_values(by=["dominance"])

# Plot horizontal bar graph
plt.figure(figsize=[10, 9])
plt.barh(df.coins, df.dominance)
```

Comment: `bars = plt.barh(...)` and `plt.bar_label(bars)`?

Comment: module 'matplotlib.pyplot' has no attribute 'bar_label'

Comment: Well, it's a new function, you need a recent matplotlib version

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the issue is that the `bar_label` is a new feature and available in matplotlib version 3.4 or later - ref this [link](https://discourse.matplotlib.org/t/axessubplot-object-has-no-attribute-bar-label/21985/2). Check the version of matplotlib using

```
import matplotlib 
print('matplotlib: {}'.format(matplotlib.__version__))
```

Upgrade to `v3.4` or latest version using `pip install matplotlib --upgrade`. You will need to include the code in the link you provided and as mentioned by JohanC and be able to see bar labels